# hom between simplical sets $\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1$ and $\Delta^1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I'm stuck on a very simple  question: Let $\Delta^1$ be the simplicial set, so $(\Delta^1)_n = Hom([n], [1])$ is the set of nondecreasing functions $f:\{0, 1, \ldots, n\} \to \{0,1 \}$. Let $sSets$ be the category of simplicial sets.

What exactly are the elements of the set $Hom_{sSets}(\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1, \Delta^1)$ ?

I know the $n$ simplices of  $(\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1)_n = (\Delta^1)_n \times (\Delta^1)_n$ and I'm guessing I only need to worry about $n=1$ because the face and dengenracy maps will then determine values for higher $n$. $(\Delta^1)_1=Hom([1], [1])$ has three elements, namely $00$, $01$, $11$ - the notation is these are the images of a map $[1] \to [1]$.

Comment: Maybe it would help you to picture $\Delta^1\times \Delta^1$ as a square and $\Delta^1$ as a line segment.

Comment: $\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1$ is the nerve of the category $(0 \rightarrow 1) \times (0 \rightarrow 1)$ and $\Delta^1$ is the nerve of $(0 \rightarrow 1)$, the nerve functor is fully faithful so maps $\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1 \rightarrow \Delta^1$ are in bijection with functors $(0 \rightarrow 1) \times (0 \rightarrow 1) \rightarrow (0 \rightarrow 1)$. We let $(0 \rightarrow 1)$ denote the category with two objects and only one nontrivial morphism which goes in between the two objects.

Comment: @NoelLundström ok thanks that helps me get out of simplicial sets which have a lot of data